# GridView SelectedValue is null after selecting a row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple GridView with a Select button. 
in the GridView.RowCommand event when I select a row I want to read the GridView.SelectedValue it is null.
The only time GridView.SelectedValue is valued with the right data is when I select the row twice.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        code_bimehTextBox.Text = GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString();//SelectedValue is null after clicking the select button but after clicking again it works right
    }
```

Comment: check GridViewCommandEventArgs

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong event. 
When using select button you should use SelectedIndexChanging and SelectedIndexChanged events.
Here is where you can find complete list of buttons/events:
[GridView.RowCommand Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

// get the values of selected row from a Gridview and display the values in textboxes using C# code.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      TextBox1.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;

  }
```